# Adding noise to a sound

Tags: matlab

I have a signal that it has an array c(500000 x 2) with two channels and one frequency fs.
I want to add a Gaussian sound to the first channel of the sound . I have create a vector and create a Gaussian sound

```
p=zeros(500000,1);
f=awgn(p,30);
sound(f,fs) ;
```

,that plays the sound with Gaussian noise.
I want now to put that noise ( f ) to the first channel of the sound .
I am new to matlab so i tried something of with awgn function

```
c1=awgn(f/2,30);
```

but it doesnt work.
Any suggestions??

Comment: Which part doesn't seem to work? Your first code block looks perfect. As long as you have `fs` defined it will now play `f` which is `p` with Gaussian noise.

Answer (score 1):

### `awgn()` Returns the Original Signal With Guassian White Noise Added to It

Seems like you already added Gaussian noise in your first step. Here is a script that you can use to test how Additive White Gaussian Noise (AWGN) affects audio. Here you hear that the `awgn()` returns the audio signal with the noise added. By playing with the `Signal_To_Noise_Ratio` you'll be able to hear more or less of the original audio due to the amount of noise distorting/obstructing the signal. Use the command `clear sound` to end playing your chosen audio file/signal.

```
File_Name = "Audio.mp3";
Audio = audioread(File_Name);

Original_Signal = Audio(:,1);
Signal_To_Noise_Ratio = 20;

Noisy_Signal = awgn(Original_Signal,Signal_To_Noise_Ratio);

%Playing back at the sampling frequency, Fs%
Fs = 44100;
sound(Noisy_Signal,Fs);
```

---

### Applying Gaussian Noise to a Trivial DC Signal:

Below shows the result of applying the Additive White Gaussian Noise on a DC signal that is constantly equal to 1. The output of the `awgn()` function is the signal with the noise added on top.

[image: Noise Applied to DC Signal]

```
Original_Signal = ones(1,100);
Signal_To_Noise_Ratio = 20;

Noisy_Signal = awgn(Original_Signal,Signal_To_Noise_Ratio);

plot(Original_Signal);
hold on
plot(Noisy_Signal);
title("Applying Gaussian Noise with SNR = " + num2str(Signal_To_Noise_Ratio));
legend("Original Signal","Noisy Signal");
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**